# How can i prevent NPM to delete locally installed modules from nodes_modules

Tags: npm

I have some local modules which are inhouse developed and I copy to my node_modules folder manually.
When I do this they work fine but after I install some other stuff via ng add or npm install the folder is removed. My question is how can I prevent this from happening so I don't have to copy the files again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify your dependencies in `package.json` or else you cannot rely on them being in `node_modules`. Various `npm` commands might remove it, notably `npm ci` but also others.

If your package is not publicly published, some options are:

- Use a non-public registry and publish it there.
- [Publish it as a scoped package with limited visibility.](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages) You will need a paid or organization account on `npm` for this. Individual accounts are US$7 a month.
- [Use `npm link` to "install" it from your local file system.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link)
- Use a `postinstall` or other [life cycle script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts) to have `npm` copy in your packages for you each time after `npm ci` or `npm install` is run.

There are likely other options, but those are the ones that come to mind immediately.